# The output from a loop is not correct

Tags: r

I have two tables `FDate` and `Task` as follows:

```
FDate
 Date Cycle Task
1:    1    90    D
2:    2   100    A
3:    3   130    B
4:    3   130    C
5:    4   180 <NA>
6:    5   200    A
7:    5   200    D
8:    6   230 <NA>
Task
 Date Task
1   NA    A
2   NA    B
3   NA    C
4    6    D
```

I want to write the `Task` name of same `Date` from table `Task` to table `FDate`. This is the code I try

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Task)) {
  FDate$Task[FDate$Date %in% Task$Date[i]]<-Task$Task[i]
}
```

This is the output

```
 Date Cycle Task
1:    1    90    D
2:    2   100    A
3:    3   130    B
4:    3   130    C
5:    4   180 <NA>
6:    5   200    A
7:    5   200    D
8:    6   230    4
```

I expect the output is `D`, not `4`. I can't find what is wrong?

Comment: Can you share your dataset using these: `dput(head(FDate, 8))` and `dput(head(Task,4))`? It is unclear what causes the issue and without reproducible data it's hard (if not impossible) to know for sure.

Comment: and give a title that is actually meaningful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the column is `factor` which gets coerced to integer storage mode value.  Convert it to `character` before looping

```
FDate$Task <- as.character(FDate$Task)
Task$Task <- as.character(Task$Task)
```

Better, would be to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` either while reading (`read.csv/read.table`) or if we are creating with `data.frame` as in both cases, the default option is `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` and it can create some issues similar to this.

---

Also, this can be done with a join (assuming the datasets are `data.table`

```
library(data.tabl)
FDate[na.omit(df2), Task := i.Task,on = .(Date)]
FDate
#   Date Cycle Task
#1:    1    90    D
#2:    2   100    A
#3:    3   130    B
#4:    3   130    C
#5:    4   180 <NA>
#6:    5   200    A
#7:    5   200    D
#8:    6   230    D
```

NOTE: changed the second data.table identifier to 'df2' instead of 'Task' as there is a column 'Task' in each dataset

Comment: You sure about that `factor` column point. I tried it with a factor and got `D` not `4` :/ (I mean it makes sense but I cannot reproduce it)

Comment: @M-M  You meant you got 4 instead of D?  OP expects the output as "D" instead of 4

Comment: Nah, I mean I read the data in, converted `$Task` to factor and still got `D`! (I cannot reproduce OP's error)

Comment: @M-M  It is unclear about the class of the columns, but if the OP gets a numeric value instead of the character, it implies the `factor` issue.  Let the OP respond